# How can I check whether a VALUE is a Proc in a Ruby C extension?

Tags: c, ruby

I have a method in a Ruby C extension that takes a `Proc` as an argument, and I would like to verify that the argument is the correct type, i.e. I would like to do the equivalent of `arg.is_a?(Proc)` but in the C code. I found the `CheckType` macro, but it looks like `Proc` is not one the list of built in types that it can check against. So, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Those macros correspond to the different types of RVALUE. To check against arbitrary classes, you use `rb_obj_is_kind_of` which is the C function that sits behind `is_a?`:

```
rb_obj_is_kind_of(some_obj, rb_cProc);
```

Note that this returns QTrue/QFalse. You should also be able to use `rb_obj_is_proc`